# x axis text overlapping c3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

When the names of x axis are big the text is overlapping. Is there any property to fix this ? Fit:true doesn't resolve the problem.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esqkw.png)

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Comment: You could use http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-tick-rotate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use x axis tick rotate, example: http://c3js.org/samples/axes_x_tick_rotate.html

There is another solution where you can use

> multiline: true

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    x: 'x',
    columns: [
        ['x', 'www.somesitename1.com', 'www.somesitename2.com', 'www.somesitename3.com', 'www.somesitename4.com', 'www.somesitename5.com', 'www.somesitename6.com', 'www.somesitename7.com', 'www.somesitename8.com', 'www.somesitename9.com', 'www.somesitename10.com', 'www.somesitename11.com', 'www.somesitename12.com'],
        ['pv', 90, 100, 140, 200, 100, 400, 90, 100, 140, 200, 100, 400],
    ],
    type: 'bar'
},
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'category',
        tick: {
            rotate: 0,
            multiline: true
        }
    }
}});
```